# Proper way of using a Service with a BroadcastReceiver & LocalBroadcastManager

Tags: android, service, broadcastreceiver

I'm not sure if my current approach is the proper way to use a Service: I would like to listen to a LocalBroadcastManager in the background (no Activity involved) and query some WebServices upon receiving an Intent. Could you please have a look at my code below and tell me if this is "good" or "bad" in regards of a robust code design? Of course I'd like to reduce the device resource utilisation to a minimum.

Originally, I had an IntentService in my mind but I didn't figure out how to start it from a BroadcastReceiver (you can't register a BroadcastReceiver in the manifest if it just listens to LocalBroadcasts).

```
public class WebRequestService extends Service {

@Override
public void onCreate() {        
    BroadcastReceiver mLocalMessageReceiver = new BroadcastReceiver() {
        @Override
        public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
            new getCurrentValues().execute();
        }
    };

    IntentFilter messageFilter = new IntentFilter(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
    LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).registerReceiver(mLocalMessageReceiver, messageFilter);
}

@Override
public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
    return START_STICKY;
}

@Override
public void onDestroy() {}

@Nullable
@Override
public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
    return null;
}

private class getCurrentValues extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, ResultDTO> {

    @Override
    protected ResultDTO doInBackground(Void... params) {
      // do some magic
        return resultDTO;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(ResultDTO result) {
        if (result != null) {
          Intent messageIntent = new Intent();
          messageIntent.setAction("currentValuesUpdated");
          messageIntent.putExtra("result", result);
          LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(this).sendBroadcast(messageIntent);
        }
    }
} }
```

Thank you very much

Comment: what is `BroadcastReceiver mLocalMessageReceiver` for in your Service? who sends broadcasts to this Service?

Comment: Initially an Android Wear application. `WearableListenerService` -> on MessageReceived() sends the initial Broadcast to the LocalBroadcastManager.

Comment: but why `BroadcastReceiver` if you can directly pass data to the Service via `startService` ?

Comment: Good question :) 
So would you suggest in the `WearableListenerService` to start an `IntentService` to do the webrequests? Or would it be better to start the `AsyncTask` right in the `WearableListenerService`'s `onMessageReceived()`-Method?